# Unserialise array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, node.js, serialization

Hello im trying to unserialize this array in javascript using PHPunserialize module :

```
a:7:{s:13:"varPertinence";a:4:{i:0;s:5:"REGLT";i:1;s:2:"13";i:2;s:2:"15";i:3;s:2:"16";}s:10:"varSegment";N;s:12:"varSSegment1";N;s:12:"varSSegment2";N;s:7:"varVoie";N;s:4:"ingr";s:7:"cafaccentxA9ine";s:2:"mc";N;}
```

and i got this error :

```
Unknown key type 'x' at position 192
```

in Php the folowing expression may fix that :

```
$myvar = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'",  $myvar );
```

this what i tried in js :

```
myvar = myvar.replace(!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e, "'s:'.$2.length.':\"$2\";'");
```

is this conversion correct?

do you have an idea about this error?

this is a working example (successfully unserialized)

```
a:7:{s:13:"varPertinence";N;s:10:"varSegment";a:3:{i:0;s:2:"21";i:1;s:1:"7";i:2;s:2:"12";}s:12:"varSSegment1";N;s:12:"varSSegment2";N;s:7:"varVoie";N;s:4:"ingr";s:6:"citrus";s:2:"mc";N;}
```

Thank you

**Edit** : thoses are two functions from where error come (unserialise module):

```
readType = function () {
      var type = phpstr.charAt(idx);
      idx += 2;
      return type;
    } //end readType

  , readKey = function () {
      var type = readType();
      switch (type) {
        case 'i': return readInt();
        case 's': return readString();
        default:
          throw {
            name: "Parse Error",
            message: "Unknown key type '" + type + "' at position " +
                (idx - 2)
          };
      } //end switch
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason this is tagged under javascript & node.js?

Comment: you can try like this 
**
    echo json_encode( unserialize( $myvar));**

Comment: Keith : my project is under NodeJs and the module im using it in Nodejs via npm,

Comment: I cannot get your expected string - where does `N` come from? Try `myvar.replace(/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/g, function(m, $1,$2) { return 's:' + $2.length + ':"' + $2 + '";' });`

Comment: Anuraj : thank you for your answer but im working in JS environment , the php code is what im trying to adapt in JS, thank you anyway

Comment: I cant tell you where N come from , because thoses are php serialized array stored in mysql table that i expect to convert them in json format.

the second array that works contains N; too so i think this is not the source of error , after all i dont understand much in php and serialized array , i understand only json , easy to use

Comment: Well, I am driving at the fact that your regex fix does not work even in PHP. Converting it to JS won't help.

Comment: I think N is when a value of key is null;

Wiktor thank you for your answer , i tried your regex but same result maybe the probleme come from serialized array in database; i try to compare working and not working example i dont find where the probleme come

Comment: I found the probleme but i need solution please : in serialized array example : 

s:7:"caféine" , unserialize reconnize probleme of utf8 format

Comment: I found the probleme but i need solution please : in serialized array example : 

when i replace special characters i forgot to update length of string :

s:4:"réré"  -> s:14:"r\u00e9r\u00e9"   

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Wiktor : could you explain me what m1 $1 $2 means please? im trying to find how to fix a small probleme with regex :

when we have something like this : 
`s:5:hello; s:2:hi`   if i try to search hi how to get only `s:2:hi` to replace `hi` by another string and `2` by its length ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The probleme of unserialization come from special characters : é à ...

the error that i made is to replace thoses charachters by right format : `é : \u00e9`

but i forgot to update the length of string before the unserialization ( adding length('\u00e9')-1  ( -1 for the replaced character)

Thank you all for your time and your help